# Селекторы комбинаторы CSS

Tags: css

```
<nav class="main_nav">
    <ul>
      <li>1</li>
      <li>1</li>
      <li>1

        <ul>
          <li>2</li>
          <li>2</li>
          <li>2</li>
        </ul>

      </li>
      <li>1</li>
    </ul>
</nav>
```

Мне надо выбрать элементы 1.
Пробую

```
nav.main_nav > ul > li {
    color:bisque;
}
```

Но выделяются все элементы.

Не понимаю в чем ошибка.
`div>span`  Выбирает все дочерние элементы `<span>`, у которых родитель - элемент `<div>`.
Сперва выбираю единственный элемент `ul` в `nav`. Потом выбираю элементы `li`, у которых родитель предыдущий `ul`. В чем моя ошибка? И как это исправить?

Comment: второй `ul` входит в `li`. А `li` окрашивается весь. Поэтому и внутренний контент окрашивается

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Цвет - это [наследуемое свойство](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/CSS/inheritance). Установив цвет в нужные вам `li`, он наследуется во всё их содержимое. Вы можете отменить этот цвет у внутренних `ul`, задав им изначальный или другой цвет явно.